# typescript overloaded Variadic generic function has `implicitly has an 'any' type` issue

Tags: typescript, variadic-functions, typescript-generics

Here is the code snippets

```js
export type actions = {
  abort: () => void;
  back: () => void;
  next: () => void;
  resume: () => void;
};

class Sabar {
  public use<T1>(fn: (arg1: T1, ctx: object, actions: actions) => void) :void;
  public use<T1, T2>(fn: (arg1: T1, arg2: T2, ctx: object, actions: actions) => void) :void;
  public use<T1, T2, T3>(fn: (arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3, ctx: object, actions: actions) => void) :void;
  public use<T1, T2, T3, T4>(fn: (arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3, arg4: T4, ctx: object, actions: actions) => void) :void;
  public use(fn: Function) :void {
    // ....
  }
}

const test = new Sabar();

test.use((first, second, third) => {}) // indicate `second` is object, `third` is actions
test.use((first, second, third, forth) => {}); // indicate `first`, `second`, `third`, `forth` as any
```

`use` function always has two tailing params `ctx` and `actions`. The heading params has variadic length.

The issue is:

1. when provide a function with three params, `ts` could indicate with correct type info..
2. However, when the provided function with four, five or more params, all these params will be indicated with `any` type...

I have attempted to google the reason for very long time... still could not get any further. Hope someone could give me a favor.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

In your example, Typescript compiler has no way to determine what the types of `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`, and `arg4` would be. You'd have to help the compiler by explicitly stating the template parameters. For example -

```
test.use<string>((first, second, third) => { })
// indicate `first` as string, 
// `second` as object, 
// `third` as actions,

test.use<string, number>((first, second, third, forth) => { });
// indicate `first` as string, 
// `second` as number, 
// `third` as object,
// `forth` as actions
```

Comment: Maybe it's the reason. However, the point make me confused is when params length is three, it could be recognized by ts compiler correctly. In this example, the difference between overloaded function is params length. I think, it should work because it already know the pattern with four params..